# What are points in sandboxed solutions resource quota

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is meant by point in sandboxed solutions resource quota. 1point equals to what?
Is it regarding any usage of that solution in the sharepoint site. Can you please any clarify this confusion?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a simple answer - 
[MSDN - Resource Usage Limits on Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615462.aspx)

I don't belive that Microsoft is open about what exactly constitute a 'point'

> resource points. These points accumulate based on a **proprietary
>   algorithm** that takes into account the use of resources in the 15
>   resource categories

Comment: @Ryan.. ya it is very big one. But i am asking is there any measurement for the point in the resource allocation?

Answer (score 0):

Per the link which @Ryan shared above, "Each site collection is subject to a configurable maximum of daily resource points. These points accumulate based on a proprietary algorithm that takes into account the use of resources in the 15 resource categories by the sandboxed solutions that are installed in the site collection."

Those 15 resource categories are outlined on the same page, directly [linked here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615462.aspx#sectionSection1)

It basically describes how number of times executed, duration of execution, failures, etc all contribute a certain amount to the total points.